# System Invalid cast Exception in NameScope

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using FluidKit in my application. Below code is working fine in .Net 3.5 but throws an exception in .Net 4.5.

```
private Viewport3D _viewport;

protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
    {
        base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);

        if (visualAdded != null)
        {
            UIElement elt = visualAdded as UIElement;
            GeometryModel3D model = CreateMeshModel(elt);
            _modelGroup.Children.Add(model);
            UpdateElementIndexes(elt, true);
            if (IsLoaded)
            {
                ReflowItems();
            }
        }

        if (visualRemoved != null)
        {
            UIElement elt = visualRemoved as UIElement;
            int index = (int) elt.GetValue(ItemIndexProperty);
            GeometryModel3D model = _modelGroup.Children[index] as GeometryModel3D;

            UpdateElementIndexes(elt, false);

            _modelGroup.Children.Remove(model);

            // Update SelectedIndex if needed
            if (SelectedIndex >= 0 && SelectedIndex < VisibleChildrenCount)
            {
                ReflowItems();
            }
            else
            {
                SelectedIndex = Math.Max(0, VisibleChildrenCount - 1);
            }
        }
    }
  private void UpdateElementIndexes(UIElement affectedElement, bool attach)
    {

        try
        {

          // Below line is giving exception :(
           NameScope scope = (NameScope)NameScope.GetNameScope(_viewport);
          ...
          ....

        }
```

The line `NameScope scope = (NameScope)NameScope.GetNameScope(_viewport);` causes the exception

> System.InvalidCastExcpetion : Unable to Cast object of type 'System.XAML.NameScope' to type 'System.Windows.NameScope'

Please help

Comment: Have you tried casting the full type name? E.g.: `System.XAML.NameScope scope = (System.XAML.NameScope)NameScope.GetNameScope(_viewport);`

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer gave good suggestion. Aslo, check your `using`s

Comment: kindly see this image http://i.imgur.com/5JtPOr3.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the most annoying error and basically what it says is that you have 2 classes with the same name but in different namespace and you're trying to cast one to another.

To get rid of the problem just rewrite this line:

```
// change this:
//NameScope scope = (NameScope)NameScope.GetNameScope(_viewport);
// into this :
System.XAML.NameScope scope = (System.XAML.NameScope)NameScope.GetNameScope(_viewport);
```

EDIT:

*You can always use `var` and compiler will do necessary namespace imports:*

```
var scope = NameScope.GetNameScope(_viewport);
```